# How to load trained weights in branching model

Tags: keras

I'm trying to add an extra branch to the original model to improve its capability.
To be more specific, the original model looks like this:

```
input1 = Input()
x1 = branch1(x1)
x1 = residualnet(x1)
model = Model(inputs = [input1], outputs = x1)
```

My improvements would be like this:

```
input1 = Input()
input2 = Input()


x1 = branch1(x1)  #1
x2 = branch2(x2)  #2

x1 = concat([x1, x2])

x1 = residualnet(x1) #3
model = Model(inputs = [input1, input2], outputs = x1)
```

In this condition, I already have trained weights to `#1` and `#3`. What is the best way to apply trained weights to those layers?

Comment: residualnet is trained to receive an input of dim N but you are forcing it to receive an input of dim N+M (as result of concat operation)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I will then add a 1x1 Conv layer to reduce the dims. Thanks. Do you have advice on loading trained weights?

Comment: are branch1/2 and residualnet sub-models?